# How to bind selection of table to an instance variable?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I bind a table to an ArrayController named Persons. If I add a textField on the window and bind it to Controller Key: selectionIndex, the textField will display the index of item I have selected.

The question is: instead of binding to a textField, I want to bind the index of selection to a instance variable of  MyAppDelegate class, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind `selectionIndexes` to a `@property` that has an `NSIndexSet*` object value or a pair of explicit methods like `- (NSIndexSet*) myIndex;` and `- (void) setMyIndex:(NSIndexSet*) aSet;` (in this case, `selectionIndexes` binds to `self.myIndex`).  The `NSIndexSet` class has a `firstIndex` convenience method that returns the (possibly only) integer value in cases where there is only a single selected value.